# Laravel 5.1 relationship with multiple database

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I am using [Laravel5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) with MongoDB in my application.

I have one default database and separate databases for each user.

I want to use relationship between user seperate DB and default DB. I try it using
`protected $table = 'default_db_name.table_name';` and i also try the solution from this laravel forum.

http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2014-many-to-many-relationship-not-working-across-databases.

The Laravel documentation and google dont seem to worked for me.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

there you can connect to multiple servers

```
'mongodb' => array(
'driver'   => 'mongodb',
'host'     => array('server1', 'server2'),
'port'     => 27017,
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'database',
'options'  => array('replicaSet' => 'replicaSetName')
```

),

Comment: Yeah but i have multiple database on same server

Comment: ok, then, `$users = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->get();`   `$users2 = DB::connection('mongodb2')->collection('users')->get();`    `'mongodb2' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 27017,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database',
    'options' => array(
        'db' => 'admin' 
    )
),`

Comment: i can't predefined connection because i have separate database for each user.